# react-select defaultValue's value has changed but not updating what is shown in the UI

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have 2 `react-select`, one is for `methodGroups`, the other is `methods`.

**methodGroups**: `[{value: 1, label: 'Group-1'}, {value: 2, label: 'Group-2'}, ...]` 
**methods**: `[{value: 1, label: 'method-1', isActive: 1}, {value: 2, label: 'method-2', isActive: 0}, ...]`

When I select from `methodGroups`, the `methods` select should automatically set all the `isActive = 1` as **selected**.

What I did was, 
**methodGroups Select:**

```
const handleGroupChange = () => {
    // fetch from api
    let { activeMethods, inactiveMethods } = apiData;
    let temp1 = activeMethods.map(obj => ({value: obj.id, label: obj.method, isActive: 1}));
    let temp2 = inactiveMethods.map(obj => ({value: obj.id, label: obj.method, isActive: 0}));

    setMethods(temp1.concat(temp2));
}

<CustomSelect
    options={methodGroups}
    onChange={handleGroupChange}
/>
```

**methods Select:**

```
const handleMethodsChange = (values) => {
    setMethods(values);
}

<CustomSelect
    defaultValue={methods.filter(obj => obj.isActive == 1)}
    options={methods}
    isMulti
    onChange={handleMethodsChange}
/>
```

At first, when I select from **methodGroups** it shows the `defaultValues` on **methods** select.

But when I select new from **methodGroups**, the props of **methods** select has changed, but the default value that was being displayed in the UI is still the defaultValue of the previous selected **methodGroups**

BTW, I made the `Select` as a separate component, like this:

**CustomSelect.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

function CustomSelect({
  defaultValue,
  options,
  isMulti,
  onChange
}) {

  // const [defVal, setDefVal] = useState(defaultValue);

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   console.log('defaultValue ', defaultValue);
  //  setDefVal(defaultValue);
  // }, [defaultValue]);

  return (
    <Select 
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
      options={options} 
      isMulti={isMulti}
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  )
}

export default CustomSelect
```